# How to replace any library from reactjs with preactjs library

Tags: reactjs, preact

I am trying to use `react-swipeable-views` library in a preactjs app. It throws an error that `react/lib/shallowCompare` is not found. 
How to replace a reactjs dependent library to a preactjs library in general?

Comment: So you've built an application using normal react to prove you don't get the error there and so it must be related to preact?

Comment: I just wanted to know whether I can use `shallowCompare` library listed in preactjs website [shallowCompare](https://github.com/tkh44/shallow-compare) instead of [react-addons-shallow-compare](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-addons-shallow-compare). If yes, how can I approach that. And I don't think its a preactjs issue. preactjs is Awesome!

Comment: Try aliasing `react-addons-shallow-compare` to [preact-shallow-compare](https://github.com/tkh44/preact-shallow-compare)

Comment: You need to aliasing react to preact in your webpack configuration. Reference  https://preactjs.com/guide/switching-to-preact